# use environment variables in CircleCI

Tags: python, circleci

I'm trying to use CircleCI to run automated tests. I have a config.yml file tat contains secrets that I don't want to upload to my repo for obvius reasons.

Thus I've created a set of env varialbes in the Project Settings section:

```
VR_API_KEY = some_value
CLARIFAI_CLIENT_ID = some_value
CLARIFAI_CLIENT_SECRET = some_value
IMAGGA_API_KEY = some_value
IMAGGA_API_SECRET = some_value
```

The config.yml, I've removed the actual values and looks like this

```
visual-recognition:
    api-key: ${VR_API_KEY}
clarifai:
    client-id: ${CLARIFAI_CLIENT_ID}
    client-secret: ${CLARIFAI_CLIENT_SECRET}
imagga:
    api-key: ${IMAGGA_API_KEY}
    api-secret: ${IMAGGA_API_SECRET}
```

I have a test that basically creates the API client instances and configures everything, this test fails because it looks like CircleCI is not correctly substituting the values...here is the output of some prints (this is just when the values are read from config.yml)

```
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
Checking tagger queries clarifai API
${CLARIFAI_CLIENT_ID}
${CLARIFAI_CLIENT_SECRET}
COULD NOT LOAD: 'UNAUTHORIZED'

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------
```

The COULD NOT LOAD: 'UNAUTHORIZED' is expected since unvalid credentials lead to Oauth dance failure

Any clues? Thanks!

Meaning there is no substitution and therefore all tests will fail....what I'm doing wrong here...by the way, I don't have a circle.yml file yet...do I need one?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**  If anyone runs into the same problem, solution was rather simple, I've simple ciphered the config.yml file as depicted here

https://github.com/circleci/encrypted-files

Then in circle.yml just add an instruction to decypher and name the output file config.yml...and that's it!

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    # update locally with:
    # openssl aes-256-cbc -e -in secret-env-plain -out secret-env-cipher -k $KEY
    - openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in config-cipher -k $KEY >> config.yml
```

Comment: See my edited question, managed to fix it mysefl

Answer (score 0):

CircleCI also supports putting in environment variables ([CircleCI Environment Variables](https://circleci.com/docs/environment-variables/)). Instead of putting the value of the environment variable in the code, you go to project settings -> Environment Variables. Then just click add variable with name and value. You access the environment variable normally through the name.